# How to get yesterdays and todays records from database using active record in codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I am using the following method to get most read news by views, but I would also like to make it show only from yesterdays and todays records.
The where() clause function is missing, i tried some ways but could not make it work

```
function getPopularNews($limit){

   $data = array();
   $this->db->limit($limit);
   $this->db->order_by('views','desc');
   //$this->db->where('pubdate >=',  standard_date('DATE_W3C', time()));
   $Q = $this->db->get('posts');
   if ($Q->num_rows() > 0){
     foreach ($Q->result_array() as $row){
       $data[] = $row;
     }
   }
   $Q->free_result();  
   return $data; 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$this->db->where('pubdate >=',  $yesterday);
```

Where `$yesterday` is (well) yesterday's date.

Something like:

```
$yesterday = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('yesterday');
```

Comment: ur logic is quite good, but for some reason is not working in my case.

Comment: What values are in the column `pubdate`?

Comment: that's what i was also doubting , btw i have these values 2013-09-01 00:08:56

Comment: I'm guessing the column type is `datetime`? Made it overly complicated. Check my edits